# zybooks 2.10.1 Finding abbreviation

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm stuck on this challenge activity in zybooks. It's asking Complete the if-else statement to print 'LOL means laughing out loud' if user_tweet contains 'LOL'.

Sample output with input: 'I was LOL during the whole movie!'
LOL means laughing out loud.

This is the code I thought would work, but I think I'm missing a piece:

```
user_tweet = input()
user_tweet = input('I was LOL during the whole movie!')
print()
if'LOL' in user_tweet :
    print('LOL means laughing out loud.')
else:
    print('No abbreviation.')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works: using input is not usefull in your case.

```
user_tweet = 'I was LOL during the whole movie!'
if'LOL' in user_tweet :
    print('LOL means laughing out loud.')
else:
    print('No abbreviation.')
```

Input allows to get user input.

Answer (score 0):

I took your if statement and replaced it with

```
if 'lol' in user_tweet.strip().lower():
```

and it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).